# Does $\exp(\nabla)$ have any meaning in differential geometry? Is it related to the usual exponential map?

Tags: differential-geometry

I understand that if we are in $\mathbb R^n$, then $\exp(a^i\partial_{x^i})$ is simply a shift operator: $\exp(a^i\partial_{x^i})f({\bf x}) = f({\bf x} + a^i{\bf e}_i)$, where $f$ is any real analytic function on $\mathbb R^n$, ${\bf e}_i$ is the $i$-th basis vector, and the summation convention is assumed.

I want to generalise this notion to manifolds. Of course, if we have a chart / parametrisation, then everything is still fine as long as ${\bf x} + a^i{\bf e}_i$ is still in the domain of the parametrisation. What if I want a chart-independent definition of such a shift operator?

My initial thought would be something like $\exp(\nabla)$ where $\nabla$ is the Levi-Cevita connection on the manifold, so that $\exp(\nabla_i)$ is some sort of shift operator on the manifold. In my mind, it might even look like

$$\exp(a^i\nabla_i)f(p)=f(\exp_p(a^i{\bf e}_i)), \tag{1}$$
where $\exp_p$ is the exponential map on the manifold at the point $p$, $f$ is an analytic function on the manifold, and the indices are taken from a given coordinate system.

I would really want this to be true, because it connects two (at least in my mind) different notions of the exponential map, and $(1)$ seems like an elegant formula that (i) is independent of coordinates, because $a^i\nabla_i$ and $\exp_p$ are not, and (ii) $\exp_p$ does require a connection to make sense.

However, I do not really know what $\exp(a^i\nabla_i)$ would really mean, and perhaps more ambitiously, can we prove $(1)$ using a coordinate system? Or is $(1)$ already manifestly true because we can use geodesic normal coordinates, and I guess the statement is true in such coordinates? Or is $(1)$ really coordinate-independent?

I am (mostly) a physicist wondering about differential geometry. Essentially I have assumed everything to be analytic. If I said anything false in this question, please let me know, and any references to read further would be welcome.

Comment: It seems to me that the generalization you're looking for is the *(unit time) flow* of a vector field $X$, often written $\exp(X)$.

Comment: @Kajelad If that's the case, I am not sure what vector field we should consider. Would the vector field be $a^i\nabla_i$? But then I am also not sure if flowing along such a vector field actually connects to the usual exponential map $\exp_p(a^i{\bf e}_i)$.

Comment: $\exp(X)$ is well-defined for any complete vector field $X$; and in general there's no obvious "special" choice of vector field. Your example in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is that the flow of a vector field with constant coefficients (in the standard basis) is a translation. I have no idea what you mean with the notation $a^i\nabla_i$.

Comment: @Kajelad Ok, let's say I want a more direct generalisation of $\exp(a^i\partial_i)$, hence why I emphasised $\exp(a^i\nabla_i):= \exp(\sum_i a^i \nabla_{\bf e_i})$, where ${\bf e}_i$ is the $i$-th basis vector from a local coordinate. Yes, in the case of $\mathbb R^n$, it is a constant vector field, but on a manifold, which vector field should it correspond to? If it is just $\partial_i$ on a local coordinate, then this is not chart-independent, which is why I want to generalise to $\nabla_i$, and ultimately how it connects to the usual exponential map.

Comment: $a^i\nabla_i$ is a covariant derivative operator, not a vector field, and it is no more "coordinate independent" than $a^i\partial_i$. Rather than fiddling with index notation, I would suggest trying to think about the $\mathbb{R}^n$ case more carefully: what *objects* does it deal with and what *properties* do you want these objects to have, and do these things make sense on a general Riemannian manifold?

Comment: @Kajelad Perhaps I should have placed emphasis on the "relationship to usual exponential map" part. My main query would be whether or not the usual exp map on the Riemannian manifold has anything to do with exponentiating a differential operator. I highly suspect the answer is yes, and couldn't figure exactly how.